# How to loop over collection of textbox and range

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I'm new to `vba` and I can't manage to do what I want although it's very simple.

I need to automatically add textbox values from a userform to my second sheet. For example in each textboxes I provide an integer and I want to put this values 1 by 1 on the range `C5:C52`.
I have the following code that loop trough my textbox collection and range `C5:C52`

```
Sub remplissageTab()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Câbles").Range("C5:C52")

    For Each txtBox In clcTxt
        For Each cell In rng
            cell.Value = CInt(txtBox)
        Next cell
    Next txtBox

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

However the results is not what I expect. It only prints the last textbox value through all ranges. But I want all values in the same order textboxes are created.

I hope I made clear explanations.
What do you think ?

Thanks a lot for your help. Lyess

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
Sub remplissageTab()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Rw as Long
Set rng = Sheets("Câbles").Range("C5:C52")

For Each txtBox In clcTxt
    rng.Offset(Rw).Value = CInt(txtBox)
    Rw = Rw + 1
Next txtBox
Unload Me
```

End Sub

Comment: I works but as expected. For example, if I populate 3 textboxes and give them respectively 1,2,3 as values. It will correctly display 1,2,3 for the 3 first cells but from cell 4 to cell 52 it displays still 3. I would like to use as much cells as textboxes in the  range that start from C5 to C52.

Comment: You haven't told us how your userform is designed. I assumed you wanted to get the values from the textboxes in clcTxt (what is that, a collection variable?), in the order in which they are in clcTxt.

Comment: The userform has 2 buttons, the first one add 1 textboxe in the userform. Each texboxes are placed in one column. The second button is to call the sub above.

Comment: @jk Each time I create a textboxe in the userform I use this lines : `Set txtBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")` and `clcTxt.Add txtBox` I thought it'be usefull to add them in a collection. I declared the variables like so : `Public clcTxt As Collection`, `Public txtBox As MSForms.Control` both as public because I thought It was a good idea to use them again after to fill in.

Comment: yes If I'm not wrong when I create a textboxe in the userform I add them in the same order to clcTxt collection. So I'd like to display textboxes values on the same order in cells.

Comment: It is better to declare txtBox within the routine which adds them to the collection and within the routine which runs through them to add the values to the cells. Only clcTxt must be declared at the top of the module to ensure the txtBox class modules stay in memory. But you can run through the textboxes without adding them to a separate collection as there already is a controls collection of the userform itself: For Each ctl In Me.Controls...If TypeName(ctl)="TextBox" Then...